# saving and printing repeated words

Tags: python, words

so i am trying to create a program that gets an input from the user and then asks for a secondary input. If there are repeated words in the second sentence it saves the word and prints it. then it asks again, if there are words that are the same as the first sentence it also saves them and prints them. if the user enters nothing it prints the number of repeated words. my code so far is

```
word_lst = []
rptd_wds = []
words = input("Words: ")
while words != '':
  word_lst.append(words)
  words = input("Words: ")
  for i in word_lst.split():
    if i == i:
      rptd_wds.append(i)
      print(rptd_wds)
```

this code is very rough. so the over arching question is how can i save repeated words so they can be counted and printed later.

when i run it this is the output

```
Words: he me there here
Words: me here
['he me there here']
he me there here
Words: 
['he me there here', 'me here']
he me there here
me here
```

Comment: Can you show what you _want_ the program to do? Meaning, an example run of a working program? Also, what's your question?

Comment: The question is not clear enought. In this type of question, you should provide some sample input-output.

Comment: i edited the question, also thanks for the fast replies

Comment: It sounds like you are just getting started with programming. Welcome, and I hope you enjoy it. However, this sort of question is generally discouraged on StackOverflow because it could very well just be a request for someone else to do your homework. You will receive better help from the community if you work until you know something specific that you need help with. It does more good to help you with one or two confusing points than to just solve the entire problem for you.